# Why is my Random number generator seeding both arrays with the same numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, random

I'm using a method to create two new `int` arrays with random numbers,
but the two array contains exactly the same numbers. Why is this happening?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] Foo1= Foo(1000);
        int[] Foo2= Foo(1000);
    }
    static int[] Foo(int length)
    {
        int[] Array = new int[length];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {          
            Array[i]=r.Next(1, 101);   
        }
        //Thread.Sleep(6);
        return Array;
    }
```

Comment: Good grief, there's a `[weird-behaviour]` tag?

Comment: With 2 followers... @BoltClock is having all the fun itseems...;)

Comment: @BoltClock Not for long.

Comment: @George Stocker: That isn't a good edit; the title no longer reflects the OP's original problem - it is half-way to *answering* the OP's question.

Comment: @Ani I think you should re-read the OPs original revision; I'm only using words he used in his original revision.  Also, if you believe somehow 'weird behavior' describes his problem better, then edit it to say so, or take the problem to [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and open a question about it there. The community will tell you in short order if my edit was 'not a good edit'.

Comment: @George: Ok, it's just the word "seeding" that I find too 'knowing'. Btw, it was just a comment; if I really thought it was horrible; I would have edited it myself, but I thought it would be better to mention it than mess around with someone else's edit. There's no 'problem' to take to meta here; so don't take offence :).

Comment: @Ani No offense taken. I see Meta as a check on the 'high rep' users' actions. If one of us takes an action that rubs you the wrong way, the natural place to talk about it is on meta.

Comment: @George: I haven't been rubbed the wrong way! It's just an edit! 
:)

Comment: @George: Can we please delete this noise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not [seeding Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx) but you're likely using it close enough between calls that the default seed is the same in both cases :

> The default seed value is derived from
>   the system clock and has finite
>   resolution. As a result, different
>   Random objects that are created in
>   close succession by a call to the
>   default constructor will have
>   identical default seed values and,
>   therefore, will produce identical sets
>   of random numbers. This problem can be
>   avoided by using a single Random
>   object to generate all random numbers.
>   You can also work around it by
>   modifying the seed value returned by
>   the system clock and then explicitly
>   providing this new seed value to the
>   Random(Int32) constructor. For more
>   information, see the Random(Int32)
>   constructor.

Answer (score 5):

it's because your random is initialized twice, with a too small time difference to have a different seed.

try this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int[] Foo1= Foo(1000,r);
    int[] Foo2= Foo(1000,r);
}
static int[] Foo(int length, Random r)
{
    int[] Array = new int[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {          
        Array[i]=r.Next(1, 101);   
    }
    //Thread.Sleep(6);
    return Array;
}
```

Comment: I would advise *against* using a static variable like this... because Random isn't thread-safe, whereas static members typically should be. Instead, create an instance of `Random` in Main and pass it into the `Foo` method.

Comment: @Jon, I updated my code to follow your advice. thx

Comment: Cool. That's a lot nicer IMO. It also demonstrates the method's dependencies more elegantly :)

Answer (score 5):

The other answers around "you're using two instances of Random with the same seed" are correct. However, they used to use a static variable to refer to an instance of `Random`. That could cause problems if you try to use it from multiple threads, because `Random` isn't thread-safe.

There are various workarounds for this (such as creating one instance of `Random` per thread, with a static method to access it safely) - I've written [quite a long article on this topic](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) which you may find useful.

Answer (score 3):

That is because of the Random class which are not really random numbers, but rather pseudo randoms. So each time a new `Random` instance is initialized in a short timespan, it begins with the same number again. If the timespan is bigger, you will have a different seed, so it would work. I would suggest to declare the `Random` instance in `Main` and hand it over to the `Foo` method, so it would look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int[] Foo1= Foo(1000, r);
    int[] Foo2= Foo(1000, r);
}
static int[] Foo(int length, Random r)
{
    int[] Array = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {          
        Array[i]=r.Next(1, 101);   
    }
    //Thread.Sleep(6);
    return Array;
}
```

Edit: I modified the code above after Jon Skeet's advice. Now the problem mentioned by him should be gone.

Comment: See my comment to Steve B - using a static variable for `Random` isn't generally a good idea.

Comment: thx, u are right, i changed that above.

Answer (score 3):

you can use global `Random` object or you can use a good seed like

```
  new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
```

Comment: Using a new Guid's HashCode as the seed is a neat trick!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using almost the same seed. Try moving `Random r = new Random();` outside of that method.